# "Shape Integrity error" on ArcMap when reading from PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, arcmap, postgresql, sql

I have a query that creates Polygons/Multipolygons from union of a polygons from table in postgres using postgis. The spatial objects created all read as valid in postgis and all are Polygons/Multipolygons. When table is read on ArcMap it throws an error "Shape Integrity error". I tried different spatial transformations like normalization, buffer with zero, simple polygon check ..., but all trials produce same error.

```
    SELECT T.id,
  ST_MakeValid(ST_Union(shape)) AS shape 
    
    FROM table T 
        
    GROUP BY T.id
```

Replicated the same query on  SQL Server with same data and table reads fine on ArcMap.

- What is the cause of the error?
- Is there a way to trace spatial objects that caused this problem on ArcMap?
- How can I solve this problem with PostGIS-ArcMap?

Update:
I tried a solution  and the geometry reads fine on ArcMap using :

```
ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(the_geom,0.0001))
```

but it produces different polygons than SQL Server with lines inside the polygons in some cases:

[image: Postgis]

[image: SQL Server]

Comment: ESRI and OGC have slightly different interpretations about how to build certain kind of polygons. Maybe your issue comes from that. See "banana polygon" in https://www.postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/validity.html and this ESRI bug report https://support.esri.com/en-us/bug/the-error-message-shape-integrity-error-is-returned-in-bug-000119406.

Comment: Without the actual geometries, we can't tell you what's wrong.  But [CheckGeometry and RepairGeometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/checking-and-repairing-geometries.htm) can.